# Apple iCloud REST Api

Tags: icloud, icloud-api

I would like to synchronise Apple calendars AND related events into my custom web calendar application. I am able to do it with Outlook and Google.  I sync Windows and Google with OAuth offline access, but I haven't found anything related to Apple Calendar.

Do OAuth/REST APIs exist for Apple iCloud accounts, preferably for use with JavaScript?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: As far as I understand, iCloud doesn't offer OAuth. You will need to work with Caldav to be able to sync a iCloud calendar.